# Can't insert PDF file into MySQL db with Python

Tags: python, mysql, file, pdf, blob

I'm stuck. I've been trying to insert a pdf file in to MySQL db but I can't. I've tried with mysql.connector and MySQLdb classes. I get nearly the same errors. I've read many posts about this issue. I tried commas, variables also. Here are my code and error;

```
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user='root', password='masatablo', db='yukleme')

c  = db.cursor()

acilacak_dosya = open("bizim.PDF", "rb")

yuklenecek_dosya = acilacak_dosya.read()

c.execute ("INSERT INTO pdfler (cizim) VALUES(%s)" %(yuklenecek_dosya))

db.commit()

db.close()
```

---

```
ERROR with mysql.connector:
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'b'%PDF-1.4\r%\xe2\xe3\xcf\xd3\r\n4 0 obj\r<</Linearized 1/L 83892/O 6/E 79669/N ' at line 1

ERROR with MySQLdb:
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'b'%PDF-1.4\\r%\\xe2\\xe3\\xcf\\xd3\\r\\n4 0 obj\\r<</Linearized 1/L 83892/O 6/E 79669/N ' at line 1")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use parameters, not string interpolation.

String interpolation with SQL is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks anyway.

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO pdfler (cizim) VALUES (%s)", (yuklenecek_dosya,))
```

Comment: Thanks @AKX, now it works. This SQL syntax is realy compelling for me sometime. I'm getting lost between commas, brackets, variables and so on. While trying alternatives, similar and targetting the first line of the attached file errors confuses programmer. Thanks again.